# Holding an MDL read lock will block the MDL write lock fetch, and after the MDL write lock fetch blocks, it will also block the MDL read lock fetch

Tags: mysql, block

##### Front

MySQL version: 5.7.36
transaction_isolation: REPEATABLE-READ
Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

##### Description

I have created three sessions.

###### session 1

```
-- ①Open a transaction
begin;

-- ② Select data
select * from test;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | A    |
+----+------+

-- ③ commit transaction
commit;
```

###### session 2

```
-- ④Modify table structure
alter table test add age int(4) not null default 0;
```

###### session 3

```
-- ⑤ Select data
select * from test;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | A    |
+----+------+


-- ⑥ Select data
select * from test;
+----+------+-----+
| id | name | age |
+----+------+-----+
|  1 | A    |   0 |
+----+------+-----+
```

Order of execution：①②④⑤③⑥
Steps ④ and ⑤ are blocking until step ③ is executed

My question:
why does step ⑤ block, it seems to me that step ② holds the MDL read lock, before step ③ is executed, and step ④ modifies the table structure to get the MDL write lock will fail because the MDL read-write lock is mutually exclusive. Step ⑤ select data tries to get MDL read lock, at this point the table only has MDL read lock which should be available, but step ⑤ blocks.
After executing step ③, steps ④ and ⑤ are re-executed, but the result is not what I expected, from here I suspect that the MDL lock is a non-fair lock after the MDL lock is released after blocking.